# cannot see iAds

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ios4, iad

I have created a new version and released it on the App store...
The new v1.1 has been approved as well..This version has the iAds code installed in it..
While testing, I was able to see "Test Adv"
But for some reasons, when I download my app, I do not see the iAds in the app..

The Ads Status in my iTunes connect says "Live Ads" and even shows a few numbers for some users..

But why do I not get to see the ads ? Is it like if I am the dev, I'll not see any ads?

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing because you are paid for views for your iAds, it makes sense that Apple doesn't serve up ads for the developer's iTunes account. The other reason you might not see an ad (assuming you try it on someone else's device) is the less than 100% fill rate.

I have never seen an iAd on my dev iPhone, but rest-assured, the ads are being shown :)

**Update**

Having a read of this article on '[Testing iAd Applications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/TestingiAdApplications/TestingiAdApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH6-SW1)', it doesn't explicitly say that ads won't be served up on the developer's account, but it does mention what sort of ads will be served based on the build type.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the same question with my app.

It turns out that there's not always an ad available to be displayed, ESPECIALLY if you are not in US.

I am in Canada and most of the time there's no ad to display.

Check you iAd Network control panel for the number of ad impressions, and sort by country.

In my case, US has over 90% fill rate (requests / impressions), while Canada is only 4%...

hope it helps...